# How do I add an empty clickTAG on html 5 banner converted by Swiffy

Tags: html, actionscript-3, flash, google-swiffy

I have successfully converted some flash banners to html5 using Swiffy.

These html 5 banners will be sent to an ad agency.

**I need some code for a clickThru tag which allow the agency to control the URL that they are directing users to.**

In flash the Actionscript would be:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.navigateToURL;

myButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onClick);
function onClick(e:MouseEvent):void {
    var click_url:String = root.loaderInfo.parameters.clickTAG;
    if(click_url) {
        navigateToURL(new URLRequest(click_url), '_blank');
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try send link as url parameter.
yourCreative.html?click_url=http://link.com

Answer (score 0):

You might try setting the FlashVars like this. See the DFP help article below for more info:

```
<div id="swiffycontainer_%ecid!" style="width: %%WIDTH%%px; height: %%HEIGHT%%px"></div>
<script>
  var stage = new swiffy.Stage(document.getElementById('swiffycontainer_%ecid!'),
      swiffyobject, {});
  stage.setFlashVars("clickTAG=%%CLICK_URL_ESC%%%%DEST_URL%%");           
  stage.start();
</script>
```

https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/6263155?hl=en